# how to set ContentPresenter Contents Background

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, contentpresenter

I have a `ListBox` which is Bound to an `ObesvableCollection` of dynamically created `UserControls`.

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox">
   <ListBox.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding userControlsCollection}"/>
         ....
      </Style>
   </LIstBox.Style>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <EventSetter Event="Selector.Selected" Handler="ListBox_Selected"/>
                    <EventSetter Event="Selector.Unselected" Handler="ListBox_UnSelected"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DefaultBackground}" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">

                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                                                      Width="{Binding ActualWidth,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=ListBoxItem,AncestorLevel=1}}"
                                                      Height="{Binding ActualHeight,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=ListBoxItem, AncestorLevel=1}}"                                                      
                                                      />                                
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                 </Style>
</ListBox>
```

I would like to set the **Background** of the selected control should be something like that

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource SelectedBackground}"/>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

but that way I set the `ListBoxItem` `Background` and it doesn't propagate the the UserControls Background...

the way I solve it now is using the Selector.Selected/UnSelected event handlers like this

```
private void ListBox_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var item = e.Source as ListBoxItem;
        var ctrl= item.Content as myControl;

        if (ctrl!= null)
        {
            ctrl.Background = new SolidColorBrush(DefaultSelectedBackground);

        }           
    }
```

Any Idea would be greatly appriciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to keep your `ItemContainerStyle` simple. If you need to mess with the `Template` of the item, use `ItemTemplate` or `RelativeSource` bindings to achieve what you need.

To get your requirement with `RelativeSource` Binding, I'd just have the `ItemContainerStyle` as something like:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="BurlyWood" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
            Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
            Value="Stretch" />
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Tomato" />
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="CadetBlue" />
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Now to get this `Background` in the `UserControl`, my `UserControl` xaml would be like:

```
<UserControl ...
             Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                 AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},
                                  Path=Background}">
```

That's it, we're sorted.

You can get the demo of this from: [**Here**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5mbksqpny2gb7y9/MvvmLight37a.rar)

**Update:**

If you're creating the `UserControl` from code-behind(not sure why you **need** to but anyways), Assign the Binding in code-behind too. Something like:

```
public UserControl CreateUserControl(string text) {
  Binding binding = new Binding {
    Path = new PropertyPath(BackgroundProperty),
    RelativeSource = new RelativeSource() {
      Mode = RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor,
      AncestorType = typeof(ListBoxItem)
    }
  };
  var uc = new UserControl {
    Content = new TextBlock {
      Text = text,
      FontSize = 24,
      FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
      HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
      VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
    }
  };

  BindingOperations.SetBinding(uc, BackgroundProperty, binding);
  return uc;
}
```

and the `ItemContainerStyle` would remain the same as before and you should be done.

Demo for this approach: [**Here**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ciixg1vm2garus0/WpfApplication70.rar)

Comment: thanks but there is no static user control, so it hard to use your suggestion the listbox is bound to an ObservableCollection<UserControl> the listBoxItem Background is set by the trigger but the Control itself doesn't get that Backround unless I use code behind...

Comment: @makc what do you mean by "static UserControl"? you mean you don't have the `UserControl` defined in xaml and you create the definition in code? If so there is still not much difference, create the same `RelativeSource` Binding in the code behind on the `UserControl` when you create it.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I meant by static, and you are right there shouldn't be a difference and I should create he binding in the code behind, I'll check that and let you know

Comment: @makc if you're having trouble with creating the `Binding` from code-behind, check the update to my answer at the bottom. You can get the demo and try it too.

Comment: this was all along in front of my face but couldn't see it, I am so use to avoiding creating binding in code behind that when it was really necessary i couldn't think of it. Thanks Viv

Answer (score 1):

To acheive what you are saying, you could wrap your `ContentPresenter` in a panel (e.g. `Grid`) and use `TemplateBinding` to set the background .

Sample Control Template:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
    </Grid>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Fuchsia" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the style trigger like this:

```
                <Style.Triggers> 
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelectedProperty}" Value="True"> 
                        <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Red" /> 
                    </DataTrigger> 
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelectedProperty}" Value="False"> 
                        <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Black" /> 
                    </DataTrigger> 
                </Style.Triggers>
```

Thanks